# Cannot find bean with qualifier. Cannot Find MessageChannel Bean

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am unable to get the following code to work. I get the following error
Cannot find bean with qualifier "messages" in the HelloController class.

I have the following dependencies

- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka
- spring-boot-starter-integration
- spring-boot-starter-web

---

```
package com.example.scs.demoscs;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoScsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoScsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.scs.demoscs;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;


public interface DemoMessages {

    @Output("messages")
    MessageChannel messages();

}
```

---

```
package com.example.scs.demoscs;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBinding(DemoMessages.class)
public class ChannelConfiguration {

}
```

---

```
package com.example.scs.demoscs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController()
public class HelloController {

    private MessageChannel output;

    @Autowired
    public HelloController(@Qualifier("messages") MessageChannel output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String SayHello(){

        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: NVM, There is no real error. Intellij is marking it as an error, but there isn't any when I run the application.

Comment: Please, consider to close then question as redundant